# WordPress - how to check if CSS file name contains ".min"?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to create a dynamic check to see if my CSS file contains the minified version style.min.css instead of style.css.

I have created a development and production mode in production it generates a minified version adding a hash and the development is just regular un minified without the .min

How can I do this the cleaner way? What if I have multiple CSS files, I don't want to copy-paste my code over and over again.

```
<?php

function nm_enqueue_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style('nm-style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    $cssFilePath = glob(THEME_DIR . '/build/css/prestigexotics.min.*');
    $cssFileURI = THEME_DIR_CSS . '/' . basename($cssFilePath[0]);

    if (strpos($cssFileURI, 'min') == false) {
        wp_enqueue_style('theme', THEME_DIR_CSS . '/prestigexotics.css', array());
    } else {
        wp_enqueue_style('theme', $cssFileURI);
    }
}   
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'nm_enqueue_style');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `function` that would make it for you. It would return an `array` with what you need.

```
<?php

function checkCssMin($filePath) {
    $cssFilePath = glob(THEME_DIR . $filePath);
    $cssFileURI = THEME_DIR_CSS . '/' . basename($cssFilePath[0]);
    if (strpos($cssFileURI, 'min') == false) {
        return [false, $cssFileURI];
    } else {
        return [true];
    }
}

function nm_enqueue_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style('nm-style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_style('theme', checkCssMin('/build/css/prestigexotics.min.*')[0] ? checkCssMin('/build/css/prestigexotics.min.*')[1] : ('/prestigexotics.css', array()));
}   
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'nm_enqueue_style');
```

*Note: I'm not very used to PHP syntax, but I hope the logic can help you. I'm sure you can simplify it even more.*

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue created a function to dynamically output the JS files.